# Who would trade a commission-based over commission-free for the same currency pair?

Tags: foreign-exchange, online-trading

(I'm a beginner)
In forex, I see that some pairs are both commission and commission-free, what is the difference?

Comment: I suppose that the commission based trades have smaller spreads that are advantageous to large trades.

Comment: @sspring I'd assume lower/no commissions would increase liquidity and cause a smaller spread

Comment: Well, retail forex brokers are essentially market-makers in a financial system that doesn't have an exchange. They stay close to institutional quotes, and close to competing forex brokers, but they set the spreads on their own system. However, they can layoff their order imbalances to institutional systems.